# Запятые в предложении: "Он как я в дурной день"

Tags: пунктуация, как, наречия

Где в предложении нужны запятые?

> Он как я в дурной день.

Comment: @Вася123, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Здесь не нужны занятые, так как "как я" является сказуемым.